# Automatically showing an NSPopover in NSStatusBar

Tags: objective-c, macos, nspopover

I've trying to make a NSPopover automatically appear below an icon in the status bar, the first time the user installs my application. Like google drive does:
[image]

I'm using the exact [code](https://github.com/djromero/PopoverMenulet) mentioned [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7906025/3854841) which works perfectly for manually showing a popover (e.g. on a user click). To get the popover to display automatically I added the following line at the end of the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method: `[self.controller menuletClicked:1]` which calls down into `showRelativeToRect...` Now this works perfectly sometimes (the popover appears right below the icon in the status bar), but other times the popover shows up at the bottom left of my screen. It works more consistently if I wait a few seconds and then execute that line of code (e.g. via `dispatch_after...`). But still occasionally fails and shows up the the bottom of my screen.

This indicates that something isn't 'ready'? (as suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18039909/3854841)) - but I've checked the popover object isn't nil, and the bounds of the rectangle look good. I've also added a loadView to try force a load, but nothing seems to work!

What is the correct way to get a NSPopover to automatically show up? Or how to ensure it will show up in the right place? thanks!!